# window.location.href not relocating the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a simple post request in nodejs with url say:
 /task1/task2/:data1
which is returning:

```
{
    result: 'success'
}
```

on successful action,  I want to go to /task route so I have done:

```
window.location.href = '/task1';
```

But this seems to be not working as it doesn't take me to the route but appends ?ts=1234566(random number) at the end of the url like:
  /task1/task2/:data1?ts=12345678910112

note: this is only happening in my localhost, seems to be working right in liveserver

Comment: JavaScript doesn't magically add things like `?ts=12345666` to your URL, so that's probably some quirkiness on your server.

Comment: Have you tried the complete url to see what the behavior is?

Comment: @theoutlander the result is same even when I put window.location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host +'/task1'

Comment: @Ja͢ck could you elaborate somemore on the issue that you think I have?

Comment: If you look at dev tools and monitor the request, what do you see in the request and response?

Answer (score 0):

`?ts` looks like it's giving you a timestamp for some strange reason.

Nonetheless, try `window.location.pathname='/task1';` and see if it gets you anywhere.

Comment: the result is same, still adds the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Some component somewhere in the tree is appending that most likely to keep your browser from caching the result.